# Ubuntu is broken after attempted LVM installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, lvm

I am trying to install LVM on an Ubuntu 14.04.4 machine, I have the system booted on `/dev/sda1`, and want to create an LVM partition on `/dev/sda2`. These are the steps I have followed:

```
apt-get install lvm2
fdisk /dev/sda (t -> 2 -> 8e -> w)
umount /dev/sda2
partprobe -s
pvcreate /dev/sda2
vgcreate vg /dev/sda2
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/vg/lv
```

After that, I restarted the server and it will not boot up again.

Comment: How is it broken? Can you please add a little more detail? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @David Foerster: sorry for the poor format. The server will not boot up again. Could the problem be that I'm installing LVM on the same drive the have the OS ?

Comment: I don't know, but I might be able do affirm or deny a connection between the two if you answer the questions of my previous comment and clarify your question (by [edit]ing it). :-) The formatting is no big deal but the lack of clarity is.